# unable to use plot command from within while loop

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to adapt an existing study to suit intraday trading, where in the buy/sell signals has to generate after session open and exit at Session close. I have defined session

```
sess = input.session('0915-1525', title='Regular Session Time')
ta = time(timeframe.period, sess + ':1234567')
in_session = not na(ta)
```

i am using a while loop determining the session is live or not and to execute the codes.

```
while in_session
    var int a
    plot (a)
    ........
    break()
```

however when i am making plot, fill, plotshape commands the below error is getting generated

line 84: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
line 89: Cannot use 'plot' in local scope
line 90: Cannot use 'fill' in local scope
line 91: Cannot use 'fill' in local scope
line 93: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope
line 94: Cannot use 'plotshape' in local scope

please advice how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see zero reasons why you need a while loop.

That being said, as the error message tells you, you cannot use `plot` functions in a local scope.

If you really need to plot something in a local scope, you should use `line.new()` instead.

Alternatively, you can apply your condition to the `series` argument of your `plot()` function. This way, you can use the `plot` functions in the global scope.

Something like this:

```
plot_cond = ...

plot(in_session and plot_cond ? plot_value : na)
```

This would only plot something if it is in the session and your plot condition is `true`. Otherwise, it won't plot anything due to `na`.